# How to continue processing after a constraint violation exception?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, database-design, spring-data-jpa

We have a Kafka consumer in a Java - Spring Boot service that has multiple instances in multiple clusters (all with same consumer group id). The consumer saves data to the database (SQL Server).

The code checks if a record exists in the `ItemSet` table before saving to the database. The actual data in the payload gets saved in a child table `ItemValue` and not the parent, `ItemSet`. The relational data table hierarchy is one to many in this order `ItemSet` -> `ItemName` -> `ItemValue`. `ItemSet` table has a `unique constraint` for department id, season combination to prevent multiple duplicate adds.

I need to do some processing after catching this exception to ensure that the incoming data still gets saved under the existing `ItemSet` and doesn't get lost. I am using Spring Data JPA and as soon as I catch the exception and try to retrieve the existing record I end up getting:

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in ItemSet entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs).

The `getItemSet()` in the catch block blows up.

What is the best way to overcome these race conditions?

```
ItemSet savedItemSet = null;
try
{
    String seasonName = itemSet.getSeasonName();
    Long seasonYear = itemSet.getSeasonYear();
    Long departmentId = itemSet.getDepartment().getId();
    List<ItemSet> itemSets = attributeSetRepository.findBySeasonNameAndSeasonYearAndDepartmentId(
            seasonName, seasonYear, departmentId);
    LOGGER.info("Found {} item sets corresponding to season name : {}, season year : {}, "
            + "department id : {}", itemSets.size(), seasonName, seasonYear, departmentId);
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(itemSets)) {
        savedItemSet = itemSetRepository.save(itemSet);
    }
    else {
        return new CreatedItemSet(itemSets.get(0).getId());
    }
}
catch(PersistenceException | DataIntegrityViolationException e) 
{
    LOGGER.error("An exception occurred while saving itemSet set", e);

    if (e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) 
    {
        String seasonName = itemSet.getSeasonName();
        Long seasonYear = itemSet.getSeasonYear();
        Long deptId = itemSet.getDepartment().getId();
        LOGGER.info("A duplicate item set found in the database corresponding "
                + "to season name : {}, season year : {} and department : {}",
                seasonName, seasonYear, deptId);
        
        ExistingItemSet existingItemSet = getItemSet(seasonName, 
                seasonYear, deptId);
        if(existingItemSet == null) {
            LOGGER.info("No item set found");
            return null;
        }
        return new CreatedItemSet(existingItemSet.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Best idea is to filter the data before you insert, rather than trying to catch exceptions

Comment: @Charlieface does that mean the insert statement itself checks if a dupe exists before inserting?

Comment: You can do that. Something like `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS...` in SQL

Comment: @Charlieface do you happen to have stumbled upon any good examples where this was implemented in JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "continue". A transaction is marked for rollback and the persistence context is unusable after a constraint violation happens.

You can either try to avoid the constraint violation, by checking if the DB contains an entry before persisting/updating, or you run the rest of your code in a separate transaction if a constraint violation happens.

Comment: Is there a way to have a query that performs an insert operation if a record doesn't exist but returns the record if it is exists? Also, how to run the rest of the code in a separate transaction? Currently, this code is in a service layer class which is annotated with `@Transactional`. Will creating a new method to handle the continuation logic and annotating it with `@Transactional` wrap the logic in a new transaction?

Comment: You need to use `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)` for creating a sub-transaction. In Hibernate there is right now no way to do an insert or update a.k.a. upsert, but this is something we plan to support in 6.2. Until then, you can use sub-transactions or check if the row exists before doing the persist, by e.g. selecting the row.

Comment: Thanks, the sub-transaction should work. I think checking if the row exists before persisting is what I'm doing today unless you're alluding to something else.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your code excerpt, you are catching an exception and then continuing to do something else within the current transaction, which is simply not going to work. Checking if a row exists before calling `itemSetRepository.save` would mean that you do not see any exception, and hence not run into the trouble of the transaction being marked as "rollback only"

Comment: I may not be understanding what you're suggesting clearly but I think doing `List<ItemSet> itemSets = attributeSetRepository.findBySeasonNameAndSeasonYearAndDepartmentId(
            seasonName, seasonYear, departmentId)` followed by `if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(itemSets))` is basically the same as checking if the row exists or not before calling `save`. The issue here seems to stem from the distributed nature of the service.

Comment: Maybe it is a timing issue, where data gets inserted between read and write which is a case you have to consider anyway. But only you can verify that the `findBySeasonNameAndSeasonYearAndDepartmentId` is sufficient for checking for existence, as you have the code.